# How to interpret Scott continuity ?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

I am having trouble of understanding what really Scott continuity means. I know the formal definition of what it is, but I don't see why it is the natural way of defining continuity.

Another question is how to interpret it on different kind of sets and order. For example if the set is power set of $A$, ordered by inclusion then a function being Scott continuous would mean                     $$\forall X \in \mathcal{P}(A)   f(\bigcup X)=\bigcup f(X) $$
Could anyone bring more examples of functions which are Scott continuous, on different sets and orders and explain how to interpret it(mainly why it is the natural way of defining Scott continuity)?
And also how to use it (the fact of a function being Scott continuous) in different kinds of problems?

Comment: As far as I know Scott continuity is originated from his domain theory. and domains have some computer-theoretic meaning (maybe a status of computation?) I guess you can get a meaning of Scott-continuity if you understand what a domain is, and why they are invented.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_continuity) on Scott continuity gives at least a little insight, and the first two chapters of *Domain Theory* by Samson Abramsky & Achim Jung, available [here](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~axj/pub/papers/handy1.pdf) as a PDF, give much more in the course of setting out the basics.